# Msgboxes following two different paths based on conditional statements

Tags: excel, vba

I have a feeling I'm over complicating things again. The script below is the basics of what I'm trying to do.  The problem I'm having is with the msgboxes.

Basically, I need a msgbox for the condition B failure (and exit for) and a msgbox for a successful loop completion.  So, they each need to follow different conditions, but i'm not sure how to do that?

```
For i = 1 To Val(days)
If hasrun = False Then
    If condition A <> 0 Then do nothing
        ElseIf condition A = 0 Then
            Do this...
    End If
If condition B <> 0 Then
    Exit For
ElseIf condition B  = 0 Then
    Do that…
End If
 Do this other code...   
hasrun = True
Next i
    MsgBox "Script exited because condition B already existed"

    MsgBox "Script finished successfully."
End if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just record the fact that a problem was found with a flag variable:

```
Dim blnBFail As Boolean     
For i = 1 To Val(days)
If hasrun = False Then
    If condition A <> 0 Then do nothing
        ElseIf condition A = 0 Then
            Do this...
    End If
If condition B <> 0 Then
    blnBFail = True
    Exit For
ElseIf condition B  = 0 Then
    Do that…
End If
 Do this other code...   
hasrun = True
Next i

If blnBFail then
    MsgBox "Script exited because condition B already existed"
Else
    MsgBox "Script finished successfully."
EndIf
End if
```